# Setting payment gateway return URL in mobile hybrid apps with angular js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, paypal, payment-gateway

We have built an hybrid app for mobile using angular js. During integration with payment gateway we are facing issue in assigning return_url to the payment gateway access. We are able to redirect to payment gateway from our mobile app and successfully complete the transaction but unable to redirect to our app post transaction. The reason behind this is setting of return_url for the payment gateway.

The app is built using phonegap and thereby we cannot set appropriate URL to return_url as in the mobile we cannot get the URL such as http://10.10.10.10:4000/test#route. The payment gateways wants the URL to be in http format and so we are not sure on how to set the return_url to the payment gateway with angular js in mobile app. The same functionality works fine as a website as angular's $location provides appropriate URL for re-direction to the website.

The issue only with the mobile. Using $location.absUrl() in mobile app returns actual file path starting with //.../www/..file. This cannot be used as gateway return_url. But on using $location.absUrl() with website returns http://10.10.10.10:4000/.. path.

Please help us in this regard.

Comment: An update to my post is that, EBS confirmed they do not support phonegap apps. Hence our hybrid app integration with EBS is kept on hold.

Comment: anyone has answer to this? I need to do the same as above.